# Exactness of the Pontryagin dual (Reference Request)

Tags: reference-request, topological-groups

I'm looking for a reference for the following result about the Pontryagin dual

> Theorem: Let $G,H,K$ be three compact abelian groups such that $$0\rightarrow G\rightarrow H\rightarrow K\rightarrow 0$$ is a (short) exact sequence then $0\rightarrow \hat K \rightarrow \hat H \rightarrow \hat G\rightarrow 0$ is also exact.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think I've seen an explicit statement of this but it is immediate from the fact that Pontryagin duality is an equivalence of categories.

Comment: @Eric Wofsey Maybe I'll look for that then.. I'll check it out.

Comment: Is this true for locally compact?

Comment: @D_S yes, me and one of my friends found a proof for this theorem using the pontryagin duality (which holds for locally compact groups as-well), unfortunately I don't remember the details completely.  I do remember that we used the fact that $\hat G \cong \hat H / Ann(G)$ so all you need to prove is that $Ann(G)\cong \hat K$.